# control SQL Server database stop/start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to know how many different ways or different reasons why database (not instance, not server, but database) is stopped/started. I am analyzing SQL Server logs.

Currently as far as I know, two possible ways/reasons are -- taking database offline/online and stop/start instance/server.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the database offline, and the if the database is set to AUTO_CLOSE TRUE then the database will automatically be shutdown when the last user disconnects from the database.  Both of these cases will show events in the log stating that the database was stopped.

Comment: Thanks! 1. Another way to start/stop database is to start/stop database instance, correct? 2. Do you think of any other ways to start/stop database?

Comment: you can start & stop a server, but not a database.  Nothing other than the 2 that i've mentioned is coming to mind...

Answer (score 1):

You can also attach / reattach a database.

Also, a database can be marked suspect, in recovery, etc.

What are you actually asking?

Comment: I find in SQL Server log, there is items like database XXX start and stop, and I want to find reasons why database start/stop because I have never explicitly start/stop SQL Server instances. Any ideas what are the possible ways we could start/stop database?

Comment: Reattach means? I am confused.